# Storyboard dummy values

Tags: ios, uikit, mockups

Is there a way to set dummy values onto my storyboard so I can see what the labels look like in development but not production? Like Android's tools namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual thing is to make your view IBDesignable and implement `prepareForInterfaceBuilder`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1402908-prepareforinterfacebuilder